# Radio Button passing null value on selecting female using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to get value on submit, but getting value which is first, its  passing null value on selecting female , onChange its working fine

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
          //  onChange={(e)=>  console.log(e.target.value)}
            {...register("myrad")}           
          >
            
<FormControlLabel value="Male" control={<Radio />}label="Male" />
 <FormControlLabel value="Female" control={<Radio />}label="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your form tag with this

```
 <RadioGroup
        //  onChange={(e)=>  console.log(e.target.value)}
        name="use-radio-group"
        defaultValue="Female"
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          {...register("myrad")}
          value="Male"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Male"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          {...register("myrad")}
          value="Female"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Female"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: its not working, instead its refreshing the page

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-vaughan-yhccz9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you soo much one more help, if you can how to error if not selected gender, make  that  label name red